# Logarithmic graph on Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to make a logarithmic graph on Excel but there's not the checkbox "Logarithmic scale" like on "normal" versions of Excel. Where is the option for Office 365?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your chart, Select the vertical axis and Right-click on it.

Select "Format Axis" from the pop-up menu

[image]

Under "Axis Options", you should see a checkbox for having a logarithmic scale on the axis

[image]

Comment: Oh! On the vertical axis! I always try to find on the horizontal one. That's dumb. Thank you!!